# Create resize image from corners

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I make resize div from corners using jquery but I need to make resize image inside div how can make it 
[see code jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gyjvzpfz/)

```
$(function(){
    //Define your element to resize
    $('#resizable').resizable({
      handles: {
        'ne': '#negrip',
        'se': '#segrip',
        'sw': '#swgrip',
        'nw': '#nwgrip',
        'n': '#ngrip',
        'e': '#egrip',
        's': '#sgrip',
        'w': '#wgrip'
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please expand on your question, from what I can see from the jsfiddle you provided there is already an image inside the resizable div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the image a `width`/`height` that is relative to it's parent container. You can do this using CSS alone:

```
#content img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gyjvzpfz/3/)